# How to apply color filter to a view

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, calayer, core-image

I've been trying to wrap my head around Core Image filters & layers but I couldn't find a solution to what I'm trying to achieve.

So I'm building an app which has a component where the user needs to draw over random shapes (here the shape is a circle for the sake of simplicity). When the user goes over the edge of the shape the stroke color must change from yellow to red.

[what I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPQsc.png)

And this is what I have so far:

[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX38x.png)

Here's how I set the "mask":

```swift
@IBOutlet private weak var tempImageView: UIImageView! {
    willSet {
        let maskImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "circle2")!
        let mask = CALayer()
        mask.opacity = 0.8
        mask.contents = maskImage.cgImage
        mask.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.resizeAspect
        mask.bounds = CGRect(x: 0,
                             y: 0,
                             width: newValue.frame.width,
                             height: newValue.frame.height)
        mask.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        mask.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        newValue.layer.addSublayer(mask)
    }
}
```

and here's where I render the drawing:

```swift
func drawLine(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint: CGPoint) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return
    }
    tempImageView.image?.draw(in: view.bounds)


    context.setLineCap(.round)
    context.setBlendMode(.normal)
    context.setLineWidth(brushWidth)

    context.move(to: fromPoint)

    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    context.addLine(to: toPoint)
    context.strokePath()

    tempImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    tempImageView.alpha = 1.0

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

However all this does is it fades the red color when inside the shape instead of giving it a different color, which I haven't been able to figure out how to do.

Comment: Don't know if this would be a good solution, but might be worth trying... Use two layers - yellow-stroke-layer below red-stroke-layer... draw the same path on each layer... mask a "hole" in the red-stroke-layer so the yellow-stroke-layer shows through.

Comment: yes! that actually works perfectly, thanks!